# Which amongst PixelGrabber vs getRGB is faster?

Tags: java, performance, image, java-2d

I was trying to implement [Hill Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher) algorithm on an image by grabbing its pixels. And it turns out that small images were loading fine.

But with bigger images (8MP or 12MP), the loading is slow; and as a result writing the image is slow too.

I was grabbing each pixel using `bufferedImage.getRGB(x,y)`, modifying it using the algorithm, and writing the pixels simultaneously using `bufferedImage.setRGB(x,y,rgb)`.

Now, I need some suggestions to make the loading/writing faster. I was wondering if `PixelGrabber` would be any better?

Comment: Since you know both approaches, what did the results indicate? (Including preliminary research/findings makes for a better question overall.)

Comment: And then, as a third possibility, look into `Raster` / `BufferedImage.getRaster()` etc, since `PixelGrabber` is antiquated at best.

Comment: @pst I am not too comfortable with PixelGrabber as it didnt work for me when I tried. getRGB always works. With PixelGrabber I always end up with a blank canvas. I used MediaTracker as well to make sure image is loaded first.

Comment: @NiteeshMehra That entire API predates `BufferedImage` (and really Java2D as we know it today). Your images have to be blitted on screen (or some other tricks with image consumers - I forget). Try rasters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getRGB/setRGB are **very slow**, because they do a lot of colorspace-checking and color-converting every time you call them. Definitely not the way to to any image-manipulation, considering the number of pixels in a typical image.

Getting the raw image data into arrays via the old PixelGrabber or via BufferedImage.getRaster() is harder (you have to understand a few concepts) but runs much faster.