# Convert BufferedImage to double [ ] [ ]

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I try to convert an BufferedImage to an double [][].

I have this code, but int the parameters i have a double [][], but in this moment i don't know how to convert my image to an double[][].

This is my function:

```
     public static double[][] reshape(double[][] A, int m, int n) {
    int origM = A.length;
    int origN = A[0].length;
    if(origM*origN != m*n){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("New matrix must be of same area as matix A");
    }
    double[][] B = new double[m][n];
    double[] A1D = new double[A.length * A[0].length];

    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<A.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<A[0].length;j++){
            A1D[index++] = A[i][j];
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<m;j++){
            B[j][i] = A1D[index++];
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```

Comment: did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image) ?

Comment: How should pixels be represented in the `double[][]` array?  Is it a monochrome image?  And if so what value represents white (1.0?) and which one black (0.0?)?

Comment: Yes..
I make the conversion rgb2gray.

Comment: *"I try to convert an BufferedImage to an double [][]."*  Why?

Comment: Because i want to have access to matrix of rgb.