# BufferedImage bytes have a different byte order, when running from Eclipse and the command line

Tags: java, eclipse, bufferedimage, endianness

I was trying to convert a `BufferedImage`'s `byte[]` from 32-bit RGBA to 24-bit RGB. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470843/2581401) the fastest way to get the `byte[]` from the image is:

```
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

So I iterate over all bytes assuming their order is R G B A and for every 4 bytes, I write the first 3 in an output byte[] (i.e. ignoring the alpha value).

This works fine when run from Eclipse and the bytes are converted correctly. However when I run the same program from the command line the same bytes are returned with the opposite byte order!

The test image I use for my test is a 5x5 black image where only its top-left corner is different having the RGBA color `[aa cc ee ff]`: [image: Test image 5x5]

And a zoomed-in version for conveniency:

[image: Zoomed-in test image]

My folder structure is:

```
- src/  
  - test.png
  - test/
      - TestBufferedImage.java
```

The SSCCE is the following:

```
package test;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TestBufferedImage {

  private static void log(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }

  private static String toByteString(byte b) {
    // Perform a bitwise AND for convenience while printing. 
    // Otherwise Integer.toHexString() interprets values as integers and a negative byte 0xFF will be printed as "ffffffff"
    return Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF);
  }

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws IOException 
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream stream = TestBufferedImage.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.png");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);
    stream.close();
    log("Image loaded succesfully, width=" + image.getWidth() + " height=" + image.getHeight());

    log("Converting from 32-bit to 24-bit...");
    DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer(); 
    byte[] input = buffer.getData();
    byte[] output = convertTo24Bit(input);
    log("Converted total of " + input.length + " bytes to " + output.length + " bytes");
  }

  private static byte[] convertTo24Bit(byte[] input) {
    int dataLength = input.length;
    byte[] convertedData = new byte[ dataLength * 3 / 4 ];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < dataLength; i+=4, j+=3) {
      convertIntByteToByte(input, i, convertedData, j);
    }
    return convertedData;
  }

  private static void convertIntByteToByte(byte[] src, int srcIndex, byte[] out, int outIndex) {
    byte r = src[srcIndex];
    byte g = src[srcIndex+1];
    byte b = src[srcIndex+2];
    byte a = src[srcIndex+3];

    out[outIndex] = r;
    out[outIndex+1] = g; 
    out[outIndex+2] = b; 

    log("i=" + srcIndex 
        + " Converting [" + toByteString(r) + ", " + toByteString(g) 
        + ", " + toByteString(b) + ", " + toByteString(a) + "] --> ["
        + toByteString(out[outIndex]) + ", " + toByteString(out[outIndex+1])
        + ", " + toByteString(out[outIndex+2]) + "]"
        );
  }

}
```

Output when run from Eclipse (Version: Juno Service Release 2 Build id: 20130225-0426):

```
Image loaded succesfully, width=5 height=5
Converting from 32-bit to 24-bit...
i=0 Converting [aa, cc, ee, ff] --> [aa, cc, ee]   // <-- Bytes have the correct order
i=4 Converting [0, 0, 0, ff] --> [0, 0, 0]
i=8 Converting [0, 0, 0, ff] --> [0, 0, 0]
.....
i=96 Converting [0, 0, 0, ff] --> [0, 0, 0]
Converted total of 100 bytes to 75 bytes
```

Output when run from command line (Windows Vista) with `java test.TestBufferedImage`:

```
Image loaded succesfully, width=5 height=5
Converting from 32-bit to 24-bit...
i=0 Converting [ff, ee, cc, aa] --> [ff, ee, cc]    // <-- Bytes are returned with a different byte order!
i=4 Converting [ff, 0, 0, 0] --> [ff, 0, 0]
i=8 Converting [ff, 0, 0, 0] --> [ff, 0, 0]
.....
i=96 Converting [ff, 0, 0, 0] --> [ff, 0, 0]
Converted total of 100 bytes to 75 bytes
```

So has anyone encountered a similar issue and/or can explain what is actually going on? Why the byte order is different when running from inside Eclipse?

Comment: Do you have different versions of Java on command line and in Eclipse?

Comment: @Joni no. Only a single JDK 1.6. is installed and both use that same JDK

Comment: Could this be a  littleEndian bigEndian problem?

Comment: @medPhys-pl In general it could be. The question here is why the behaviour is different in both environments. Here I am reading the same file with the same program so I should have either big-endian behaviour or little-endian behaviour but not both

Comment: @Joni it seems that you have a valid point. It seems that they are executed with different JREs (this is a little embarassing!). Eclipse shows Java runtime version: 1.6.0_16-b01 (JDK), but command line 1.6.0_31-b05 (JRE only). Still though I wouldn't expect the different behaviour. Perhaps I am hitting some old bug?

Comment: I think the order of bytes in the data buffer is specified independently of the buffer, in the sample model or color model or color space - I have yet to figure out where exactly - maybe you could check if they also differ?

Comment: Could it be that Eclipse adds some extra stuff on the classpath, that makes ImageIO use a different `ImageReader` for reading the PNG when running from Eclipse, versus the command line? Also, it would be good to print the value of `image.getType()`.

Comment: @Joni both versions use `ComponentColorModel` and `PixelInterleavedSampleModel`. I am wondering though if the PNG loader class has changed between versions (in both it shows `com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader`) since that would handle the creation details of the models, no?

Comment: @haraldK see my answer above. Both use the same reader class but that was good thinking.

Comment: @c.s. You could potentially have two different classes (versions of the reader) loaded at different, or even at the same time. Try `ImageIO.getImageReaders(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(stream))` and print out all readers in the iterator. In any case, the band offsets of the `PixelInterleavedSampleModel` should tell you the order of the R, G and B samples.

Comment: @haraldK that last comment of yours helped me to understand what was going on. I knew the reader versions were different however I didn't quite understood how their differences affected the image loading. After you have mentioned the band offsets it was clear to me. Please read my answer if you are interested. Many thanks to you and Joni :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before answering my own question I would like to really, really, REALLY thank @Joni and @haraldK that pointed me to the right direction. My knowledge for the internals of the `BufferedImage`, `ColorModel`, `SampleModel` and the like is not so great so they have helped me out.

So here is what happened:

First of all the different behaviour was caused by different JREs. A log statement for printing the java version revealed that Eclipse prints `1.6.0_16-b01` while the command line prints `1.6.0_31-b05`. Apparently the implementation of the image loading (this would be the `PNGImageReader` class) has changed between versions and I suspect that it did during [this change](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6549882).

Still though both versions use the same `ColorModel` and `SampleModel` so I couldn't understand this change (it seemed a real code-breaker to me) so I have investigated further.

The important change between the two versions of the `PNGImageReader` was in the `Iterator<ImageTypeSpecifier> getImageTypes()` method that decides the available compatible formats that can be used to create the new image:

version 1.6.0_16-b01:

```
...
case PNG_COLOR_RGB_ALPHA:
    // Component R, G, B, A (non-premultiplied)
    rgb = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
    bandOffsets = new int[4];
    bandOffsets[0] = 0;
    bandOffsets[1] = 1;
    bandOffsets[2] = 2;
    bandOffsets[3] = 3;

    l.add(ImageTypeSpecifier.createInterleaved(rgb,
                                               bandOffsets,
                                               dataType,
                                               true,
                                               false));
    break;
```

version 1.6.0_31-b05:

```
...
case PNG_COLOR_RGB_ALPHA:
    if (bitDepth == 8) {
        // some standard types of buffered images
        // wich can be used as destination
        l.add(ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(
                                           BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR));

        l.add(ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(
                                           BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
    }

    // Component R, G, B, A (non-premultiplied)
    rgb = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
    bandOffsets = new int[4];
    bandOffsets[0] = 0;
    bandOffsets[1] = 1;
    bandOffsets[2] = 2;
    bandOffsets[3] = 3;

    l.add(ImageTypeSpecifier.createInterleaved(rgb,
                                               bandOffsets,
                                               dataType,
                                               true,
                                               false));
    break;
```

So in the newer version, the new `ImageTypeSpecifier`s say to the PNG loader that a compatible image for the internal representation is the `BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` and since it is the first type in the list, the loader goes ahead and uses that. This is why the bands for the color channels (and thus the bytes) are reversed.

Realizing the above, it suddenly hit me that this was not a bug nor a code breaker as I thought. The reason is that because I was using `byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();` to get the bytes I was actually hacking my way to the internal data structures (i.e. ignoring the `SampleModel`) of the image. Nothing in the contract of the `ImageReader` guarantees the order of the bytes. It is free to change its internal data stuctures if it wants (this is the point of encapsulation right?). The way to correctly configure an `ImageReader` if you desire anything else than the default behaviour is to get its default `ImageReadParam` and configure it. Then pass it back to the reader by using `reader.read(imageIndex, param);`

Since I actually want the reader to return a specific format for the image bytes I should do this:

```
log("Java version: " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));

// get the reader
ImageReader ir = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("png").next();

// get the default param    
ImageReadParam p = ir.getDefaultReadParam();
p.setDestinationType(
    // define the image type to return if supported
    ImageTypeSpecifier.createInterleaved(
        ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), 
        new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3},    // <-- the order of the color bands to return so the bytes are in the desired order
        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE,
        true, false)
        );

InputStream stream = TestBufferedImage.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.png");

ImageInputStream imageStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(stream);
ir.setInput(imageStream);
BufferedImage image = ir.read(0, p);
```

Now both versions will return the order of the bytes in the same RGBA form i.e. the output for the different color will print in both cases:

```
...
i=0 Converting [aa, cc, ee, ff] --> [aa, cc, ee] 
...
```