# How to check fast the color of the pixels on a bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I go through a bitmap in android and i want to get a the color of each pixel and count it if it has a certain value i.e if it is brown.

I use the following code. The code works but it is extremely slow due to the big number of pixels in the image, which of course I need for correct results.

```
for(int i =  1; i <= 100; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
        int pixel =  bitmap.getPixel(i,j);

        R1 = Color.red(pixel);
        G1 = Color.green(pixel);
        B1 = Color.blue(pixel);

        if((R1 == 155) && (G1 == 155) && (B1 == 155)) {
            countthecolor = countthecolor + 1;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Did you try android.graphics.ColorMatrix ?

Comment: No. Can you tell me how?

Comment: there is ColorMatrixColorFilter that can be set to Paint object when drawing a Bitmap

Comment: @psink ColorMatrix is good to apply transformations, but I'm not sure how it helps count the colors present.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `getPixels` which returns a large array of `length = bitmap.width * bitmap.height`.

Then you can loop through this array and perform your operation. This will be a little faster however, now you will have to manage your memory since you already have the bitmap and now this array in the memory. So I recommend to recycle the bitmap if you don't need it anymore.

```
int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), x, y, myBitmap.getHeight(), myBitmap.getWidth());
```

You can further optimize your loop using bitwise operations to get the individual RGB values (note for alpha may or may not be there):

```
            Alpha = (pixel & 0xff000000)  
            R1 = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            G1 = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            B1 = (pixel & 0xff);
```

May want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470843/827110)!

Comment: You can also use `getPixels` to grab a row at a time using the `height` and `offset` parameters. This won't be as fast as reading the whole thing in at once, but it will alleviate most memory concerns.

Comment: I failed to mention this operation takes place on a frame preview. onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera mCamera)                            So is this going to be fast enough?

Comment: It will be *much* faster than reading individuals pixels, either way. "Fast enough" depends on how fast you need it. Give a shot and see.

Comment: I will try. i will need to use a loop to go through the array, right?

Comment: It works and it takes just the 1/3 of time. I guess i will use coding to get is with less time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should mark it `answered` if your problem is resolved and the answer helped you.

Comment: For the alpha value, use `pixel >>> 24` instead of `(pixel & 0xff000000)` (which by the way doesn't give you a value between 0 and 255). Also use the `>>>` logical shift operator here, otherwise you get `-1` for 255 alpha value

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getPixel` for each each pixel will take a while. [`getPixels`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) will let you perform calculations on a row of pixels at once.