# Get pixel data from a BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I need to obtain the pixel data from a BufferedImage so I can recreate the image from the data.  I looked into `Raster`, but that did not seem to contain the information I need. How can I obtain data from a `BufferedImage` so I can recreate the image without needing the original file?

Comment: What do you mean with recreate without the original file?

Comment: I want to obtain the image's data (pixel color, size, etc) and save and recreate the image from that data.

Comment: [this example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#lc) or [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#rccig) may help.

Comment: Do you need pixel access, to manipulate the image data, or is the idea just to avoid needing the original fileIs it a requirement to do it in memory, or is it okay to store to (another) file?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the answers to this question

[Java - get pixel array from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image)

One way to do it is to use

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

Now when you want to create a new `BufferedImage` from the data you use

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage newImage = null;
try {
    newImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: How do I apply that pixel data to another BufferedImage?

Comment: @Charsmud Good question! I have added instructions in the answer.

Comment: @Craigy You can not read a byte array back, using ImageIO, like in your example. ImageIO reads images stored in a file format. Although your code compiles, `newImage` will be `null`. You need to recreate using `new BufferedImage(colormodel, raster, colormodel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null)` (ie, you need to know the `ColorModel` as well as the raster).

Comment: @haraldK you're right. I have updated the answer so that the image can be recreated.