# DataBuffer to DataBufferByte cast throws error

Tags: java

I have the following java code

```
final byte[] pixels;
DataBuffer rasterData = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
DataBufferByte rasterByteData = (DataBufferByte)rasterData;
pixels = rasterByteData.getData();
```

Where image is a object of type `BufferedImage`, I wish to convert the `Image` to a `DataBufferByte` object but my cast throws the following error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.DataBufferInt cannot be
>   cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferByte

I am trying to use the code from this post [Java - get pixel array from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image)

Any ideas how to cast or why I cannot cast from `DataBuffer` to `DataBufferByte`?

EDIT: Changed `Image` to `BufferedImage`

Answer (score 1):

> DataBuffer to DataBufferByte cast throws error

Look at [reference API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBuffer.html) - raster data can be anything not only bytes. So i think this is reason why you are getting Exception.

Try to use for your `BufferedImage` property:

```
BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR
```

this should fix it and raster data should be returned as bytes.

Comment: Before I try to do this cast I also cast an `Image` object to a `BufferImage` object. My question I guess is then, how do I convert a `Image` to a `DataBufferByte`? How might in my cast I use `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`, should it just be `(BufferImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)image`? // EDIT, trying that gives me errors in my IDE.

Comment: You cannot cast image like this, you need to create image as `BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);`

Comment: How would I write my `Image` into this new `BufferedImage` object?

Comment: Nevermind I have found the information elsewhere! // `BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        image.getGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);`

Answer (score 0):

DataBuffer is the super class of DataBufferByte class so you can not assign ref of superclass object to subclass object

You will always get class cast exception while do so.

http://edelstein.pebbles.cs.cmu.edu/jadeite/main.php?api=java6&state=class&package=java.awt.image&class=DataBufferByte