# Bit manipulation of int in java, print information contained within int

Tags: java, colors, bufferedimage, pixel, raster

In the code below (in the else statement) I am trying to get the value for the red blue and green parts of the given pixel. I am not sure how to get the value from the int. This code is from another stack post [Java - get pixel array from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image) I am trying to modify it to tell me if it has found a pixel of a specific color (I know the RGB of this color and want to compare each pixel).

How can I get each R, G, and B in the 0-255 value range?

```
private static int[][] convertBImageToArr(BufferedImage image) 
    {
        final byte[] pixels;
        DataBuffer rasterData = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
        DataBufferByte rasterByteData = (DataBufferByte)rasterData;
        pixels = rasterByteData.getData();
        final int width = image.getWidth();
        final int height = image.getHeight();
        final boolean hasAlphaChannel = image.getAlphaRaster() != null;

        int[][] result = new int[height][width];
        if (hasAlphaChannel) 
        {
            final int pixelLength = 4;
            for(int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel += pixelLength) 
            {
                int argb = 0;
                argb += (((int) pixels[pixel] & 0xff) << 24); // alpha
                argb += ((int) pixels[pixel + 1] & 0xff); // blue
                argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 2] & 0xff) << 8); // green
                argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 3] & 0xff) << 16); // red

                result[row][col] = argb;
                col++;
                if (col == width) 
                {
                    col = 0;
                    row++;
                }
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            final int pixelLength = 3;
            for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel += pixelLength) 
            {
               int argb = 0;
               argb += -16777216; // 255 alpha
               argb += ((int) pixels[pixel] & 0xff); // blue
               argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 1] & 0xff) << 8); // green
               argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 2] & 0xff) << 16); // red

               if(row == 11 && col == 11)
               {
                System.out.println("B:" + ((int) pixels[pixel] & 0xff));
                System.out.println("G:" + (((int) pixels[pixel + 1] & 0xff) << 8));
                System.out.println("R:" + (((int) pixels[pixel + 2] & 0xff) << 16));
               }

               result[row][col] = argb;
               col++;
               if (col == width) 
               {
                  col = 0;
                  row++;
               }
            }
        }
        return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you want :

```
System.out.println("B:" + ((int) pixels[pixel] & 0xff));
System.out.println("G:" + (((int) pixels[pixel + 1] & 0xff)));
System.out.println("R:" + (((int) pixels[pixel + 2] & 0xff)));
```

Comment: Please flag this answer as the chosen answer.