# Determine whether an image is grayscale in Java

Tags: java, awt, javax.imageio

I'm using something along the lines of this to do a (naive, apparently) check for the color space of JPEG images:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        File f = new File(args[0]);

        if (f.exists())
        {
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
            ColorSpace cs = bi.getColorModel().getColorSpace();

            boolean isGrayscale = cs.getType() == ColorSpace.TYPE_GRAY;
            System.out.println(isGrayscale);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this reports `false` for images that (*visually*) appear gray-only.

What check would do the right thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
File input = new File("inputImage.jpg");

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input); 

Raster ras = image.getRaster();

int elem = ras.getNumDataElements();

System.out.println("Number of Elems: " + elem);
```

If the number of elems returns 1, then its a greyscale image. If it returns 3, then its a color image.

Comment: Will this recognize images that are saved in full color, but contain gray pixels only?

Comment: No. But, this will serve as the first step of filtering out the images have one channel. For the next stage you just copy the pixels into a 3D array and check the elements. After it has gone through this stage as well, it becomes a fool proof way of determining it.

Comment: if (numofChannels == 3){
    int[][][] Imagepixelinfo = new int[imWidth][imHeight][numofChannels]; 
   // 3d array with the pixel info

   imageArray(image);// sets the array

colorORbw = typeChecker(Imagepixelinfo);
 // tells if the image is b/w or color by returning true or false after checking the individual elements
}

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. The situation that question was for is no longer relevant for me, but I'll switch the accepted answer anyway because your post contains usable code.

Comment: Thank :). I appreciate the gesture.

Answer (score 2):

the image looks like gray beacuse the `r=g=b` but actually it is a full color image, it has three channel `r g b` and the `real gray` image only have one channel

Comment: Yes, I figured that out already. ;) The question is, is there a smarter check that does the right thing?

Comment: the simplest way is to check the r g b when it have three channels

Comment: @Tomalak examine each individual pixel using information from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image and evaluate whether R, G, and B are all equal for every pixel.