# Speed up the processing of an image which uses PixelGrabber

Tags: java, image, pixel

I am writing a program which which will divide an image into **domains** and **ranges**. In this domain will be **16X16** matrix. I am using **`PixelGrabber`** to acquire the pixels. I have used for loop for the iteration but it is taking so much time to process.In java any alternate is there to reduce this time. I need a better performance. Whether we can use any collections for that?

My code is:

```
int[] pix = new int[16 * 16];
long start = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 512; i += 16) 
{
 for (int j = 0; j < 512; j += 16) 
 {
   PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(Im, i, j, 16, 16, pix, 0, 16);
   pg.grabPixels();
   makeStack(pix, i, j);
 }
}
long end = System.nanoTime();
```

Comment: If I thought this through correctly both for loops together run a shocking 262144 times. How about trying out to let those loops run parallel (multiple threads)? Don't forget to use a data structure that supports parallel writing though. In the best case your working time could be reduced close to a minimum of SINGLETHREADINGTIME/AMOUNTOFTHREADS!

Comment: What is `Im`? What is `PixelGrabber`?

Comment: Why not `BufferedImage#getRGB(int, int)`?

Comment: @kadaj: Getting single pixel values is a pretty slow operation.

Comment: Use byte array instead. `byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image

Answer (score 1):

Your problem right now is that you don't know why it's slow. Yes, it's somewhere in the code above but you can't tell us where *exactly*.

You should really run the code using a profiler to see where it spends most of the time.

That said, for image processing, it's usually most useful to convert the whole image into a `byte[]` or `int[]` array and then process that directly.