# bitmap search depending on image color android

Tags: android, bitmap

**i'm developing android application and have list of images bitmap all i need taking image from mobile cam and search in images list and retrieve the Similar images depending on color **

Answer (score 0):

Try to read every pixel anyhow; alternatively, you can obtain the data buffer from the image and directly obtain the pixels as an int[] array , see: [Java Colour Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178978/java-colour-detection). Later try something like this:

```
if (pixelValue == red) { redCounter++; }
```

Take into consideration save the predominant color and compare both images with them. (For Instance: iTunes show the predominant color of the album).