# How to detect color from PDF java

Tags: java, pdf, itext7, pdf-viewer, pdfstamper

Is there any way, in java, to automatically detect the colors of a certain area in the PDF and either translate them to RGB or compare them to the legend and then get the color?

Comment: Do you want the color with which some text or some form in that area is originally drawn? Or do you want the color eventually being visible there?

Comment: What is the "the legend"? Also, it might help you get a good answer if you clarified why detecting the color is important.

Answer (score 0):

The way I know is to Convert the pdf into a picture and then get the pixel array of the image
You can take the Hint from [Java Color Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178978/java-colour-detection) or from [Get Pixel array of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image)