# Querying Image Orientation

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, bmp

I am using code similar to [Java - get pixel array from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image) to get low-level access to pixel data of a BMP image, along the lines of:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
DataBuffer buffer = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
byte[] rawPixels = ((DataBufferByte) buffer).getData();
```

The resulting array is laid bottom to top (ie. its first bytes are the beginning of the last image line), which makes sense considering that [BMP files usually have the same layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_array_.28bitmap_data.29).

I would like to hide this low-level detail from callers by flipping the lines in this situation. Is there a way I can query the pixels orientation/layout of the loaded `BufferedImage`?

Comment: Are you sure about this behavior? What Java version and `ImageReader` class do you use? 

I just checked the source code of the Java 7 `BMPImageReader`, and it does translate from bottom-up to top-down while reading, as I expected. 

I think what you describe just might be possible, using a special subclass of `SampleModel` that translates all incoming y-coordinates, but there's no standard method to query for orientation (all `Raster`s are assumed to be top-down).

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, as I could confirm by drawing an ad-hoc 2x2 pixels image and checking the resulting array. I suppose I have an UV mapping error later in my shader...

Comment: Can you make an answer so that I can accept it, or should I close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the source code of the Java 7 `BMPImageReader`, and it does translate from bottom-up to top-down order while reading, as I expected it to do. The `DataBuffer`s backing array will thus be in the normal top-down order. I cannot reproduce this behavior using Oracle Java 7 JRE on Windows.

The OP has verified that the problem was indeed in another part of the code, not posted as part of the question.

I think what is described just might be possible, using a special subclass of `SampleModel` that translates all incoming y-coordinates, but there's no standard method to query for orientation (all `Rasters` are assumed to be top-down).

Anyway, just for fun, I created some code, to test if it is at all possible. Below is a fully runnable example.

```
public class SampleModelOrientationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(16, 9, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
        DataBuffer dataBuffer = raster.getDataBuffer();

        SampleModel sampleModel = image.getSampleModel();

        QueryingDataBuffer queryBuffer = new QueryingDataBuffer(dataBuffer, sampleModel.getWidth(), sampleModel.getNumDataElements());
        sampleModel.getDataElements(0, 0, null, queryBuffer);
        System.out.println(queryBuffer.getOrientation());

        queryBuffer.resetOrientation();
        SampleModel bottomUpSampleModel = new BottomUpSampleModel(sampleModel);
        bottomUpSampleModel.getDataElements(0, 0, null, queryBuffer);
        System.out.println(queryBuffer.getOrientation());
    }

    private static class QueryingDataBuffer extends DataBuffer {
        enum Orientation {
            Undefined,
            TopDown,
            BottomUp,
            Unsupported
        }

        private final int width;
        private final int numDataElements;

        private Orientation orientation = Orientation.Undefined;

        public QueryingDataBuffer(final DataBuffer dataBuffer, final int width, final int numDataElements) {
            super(dataBuffer.getDataType(), dataBuffer.getSize());
            this.width = width;
            this.numDataElements = numDataElements;
        }

        @Override public int getElem(final int bank, final int i) {
            if (bank == 0 && i < numDataElements && isOrientationUndefinedOrEqualTo(Orientation.TopDown)) {
                orientation = Orientation.TopDown;
            }
            else if (bank == 0 && i >= (size - (width * numDataElements) - numDataElements) && isOrientationUndefinedOrEqualTo(Orientation.BottomUp)) {
                orientation = Orientation.BottomUp;
            }
            else {
                // TODO: Expand with more options as apropriate
                orientation = Orientation.Unsupported;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        private boolean isOrientationUndefinedOrEqualTo(final Orientation orientation) {
            return this.orientation == Orientation.Undefined || this.orientation == orientation;
        }

        @Override public void setElem(final int bank, final int i, final int val) {
        }

        public final void resetOrientation() {
            orientation = Orientation.Undefined;
        }

        public final Orientation getOrientation() {
            return orientation;
        }
    }

    // TODO: This has to be generalized to be used for any BufferedImage type.
    // I justy happen to know that 3BYTE_BGR uses PixelInterleavedSampleModel and has BGR order.
    private static class BottomUpSampleModel extends PixelInterleavedSampleModel {
        public BottomUpSampleModel(final SampleModel sampleModel) {
            super(sampleModel.getDataType(), sampleModel.getWidth(), sampleModel.getHeight(),
                  sampleModel.getNumDataElements(), sampleModel.getNumDataElements() * sampleModel.getWidth(),
                  new int[] {2, 1, 0} // B, G, R
            );
        }

        @Override public Object getDataElements(final int x, final int y, final Object obj, final DataBuffer data) {
            return super.getDataElements(x, getHeight() - 1 - y, obj, data);
        }

        @Override public int getSample(final int x, final int y, final int b, final DataBuffer data) {
            return super.getSample(x, getHeight() - 1 - y, b, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never had to dwelve that deep into ImageIO API; I actually expect it to isolate me from this level of details :) My understanding of your code is that the situation I initially (wrongly) suspected can be crafted, but this is not the "standard" behavior to be expected of this API. Thanks for your time investigating this!

Comment: For the record, I finally understood my issue: I was using a basic Targa image loader, which returned the pixels array as is. And it appears that, similarly to BMP, it is stored from bottom to top. This, combined with [OpenGL conventions wrt texture loading](http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-1632.html), led to a properly oriented image (the two successive swappings canceled each other). Until I replaced it with a standard BMP loader, that is :)