# Need a way to get the Text in the Image in Black/white

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a colored textual Image to be in black and white.
Specifically the **text to be in black** and **background to be in white** for whatever colored it might be

I am using JAVA to perform this operation.

Can anybody help me out to with a code snippet or point me to a discussion which is useful.

Comment: what is the color of your colored texture image?

Comment: You could improve your question providing an input image and the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to develop your own converter RGB to Black/White, please check [Java - get pixel array from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image) . Here you import a image, access the pixel and with a specific threshold of the color you can decide to convert to black or white.

Or you use http://www.imagemagick.org/ as commandline tool (with api http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php).

Regards

Comment: I might not know the color of the image at run time. I need a way to get the image in black or white, with text in black and background in white no matter what color it is in.