# array out of bound exception occured in getRaster method

Tags: java, arrays, exception, raster

I am reading a file and trying to get image width and height. However, I am getting an exception whenever I am calling this line

```
inImg.getRaster().getPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels);
```

The exception I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 307200
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getPixels(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:1014)
at sobel_java.main(sobel_java.java:22)
```

My code is

```
public class Sobel {   

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{   

  int     i, j;   
  double  Gx[][], Gy[][], G[][];   
  FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("lena.bmp");   
    BufferedImage inImg = ImageIO.read(inFile);   
    int width = inImg.getWidth();   
    int height = inImg.getHeight();   
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];   
    int[][] output = new int[width][height];   
    inImg.getRaster().getPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels);  

}}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This link is helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image

Comment: Try to log the size of the value returned by getRaster() an the size of your pixels array, as well as height and width parameters, it will help you find out what doesn't fit there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPixels()` method stores all samples of your raster into the output array, more than one per pixel. You can get number of samples per pixel using `getNumBands()`. Increase the length of your output array:

```
int numBands = inImg.getRaster().getNumBands();
int[] pixels = new int[width * height * numBands];
```