# setRGB with BufferedImage provides incorrect coloring

Tags: java, opencv, byte, arrays, bufferedimage

I was working with BufferedImages, particularly with using setRGB. What I did was take the exact RGBA byte values and reapply them over the image to see if they worked, and the image somehow got mutilated. What did I do wrong?

```
BufferedImage subImg = inputImage.getSubimage(20,20,200,300);
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) subImg.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
int pixLength=0;
if(subImg.getAlphaRaster()!=null){
         for(int y=0; y<subImg.getHeight(); y++){
                    for(int x=0; x<subImg.getWidth(); x++){
                            inputImage.setRGB(20+x, 20+y,pixels[pixLength+3]<<24 + pixels[pixLength+2]<<16 + pixels[pixLength+1]<<8+pixels[pixLength]);
                            pixLength+=4;
                    }
         }
 }
```

Based off this post: [Java - get pixel array from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image/9470843#9470843)

it seemed like the right thing to do. However, when I print the image the subsection now looks completely different even though it shouldn't have changed. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have also tried setRGB using a new Color with rgba values, but that also didn't work. Doing

```
inputImage.setRGB(20+x, 20+y,((int)pixels[pixLength+3]&0xff)<<24 + ((int)pixels[pixLength+2]&0xff)<<16 + ((int)pixels[pixLength+1]&0xff)<<8+((int)pixels[pixLength]&0xff)]);
```

also doesn't work. I am quite clueless!

Answer (score 0):

The sequence should be:

1. alpha (`pixLength`)
2. blue (`pixLength + 1`)
3. green (`pixLength + 2`)
4. red (`pixLength + 3`)

Also, [addition precedents shift](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html); thus, you should change setRGB to:

```
inputImage.setRGB(20 + x, 20 + y, (((int)pixels[pixLength] & 0xff) << 24) + ((int)pixels[pixLength + 1] & 0xff) + (((int)pixels[pixLength + 2] & 0xff) << 8) + (((int)pixels[pixLength + 3] & 0xff) << 16)]);
```

Comment: I tried that, but what ends up happening is the whole subsection becomes transparent. Not sure why

Comment: Did you add the extra parenthesis, between each addition?

Comment: Could pixels not be correct with rgba colors? I checked its length and it is 1283568 when it should be 200*300*4 = 240,000 at most.

Comment: what is you inputImage type? is it BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB?