# ByteArrayOutputStream length < width * height

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing

I have a strange issue with ByteArrayOutputStream. I am trying to input an image and convert it to an array of bytes. The image is 270 x 480 pixels. However if I set data to the byte array and output data.length I get 21195 however 270 x 480 = 129600. Shouldn't they be the same? What am I doing wrong here?

```
BufferedImage originalImage =
                                  ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\use\\Pictures\\mypic.jpg"));

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write( originalImage, "jpg", baos );
        baos.flush();
        data = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
```

thanks,

Comment: You're missing that the file format doesn't store plain pixel-values. Try to read/write a `bmp` and you'll see that it takes roughly width*height*3 bytes (plus some overhead for the header)

Answer (score 1):

You are right if each pixel consumes exactly one byte for storage in the image format. It is not the case actually.

**Different file formats have different storage cost for a pixel.**

*For a pure black and white (not grayscale) image, every pixel need only a bit.*

In PNG images with transparency, In addition to Red,Green and Blue components each pixel contains alpha component (transparency/opacity) too. So, number of bytes in a representation of an image depends on the image format and compression.

`BufferedImage` class lets you manipulate any pixel by its position.

```
try {
  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

You can use `getRGB(int x, int y)` and `setRGB(int x, int y)` methods to get or set specified pixel.

Comment: So how do I modify my code such that my image gets converted perfectly into a 2d array?

Comment: See here for an answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image

Comment: The java BufferedImage class lets you manipulate any pixel by its position.

Comment: @jacksonecac My answer is edited with what you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

`length < width * height` can only happen if your image is binary, so if the type is TYPE_BYTE_BINARY. In that case, the encoding/storage is done line by line, and the number of byte element in your image is then `[width/8 + min(width%8, 1) ] * height`.

It can be superior in case of images with multiple channels/bands, so color images.

Before to convert an image into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, make sure the image is encoded using Byte.