# get RGB faster in android

Tags: performance, android-studio, bitmap, android-canvas, rgb

The following is my way to get eh RGB color and change the color in temp (Bitmap)  when the color in bitmap (another Bitmap) is green. But the performance is quite bad and the time used around 20 secs or more. Is there any ways for me to improve it ? Thank you very much.

```
 //get the green color of each pixel
    color = new int[bitmap.getWidth()][bitmap.getHeight()];
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
            color[x][y] = temp.getPixel(x, y);
            if (bitmap.getPixel(x, y) == Color.GREEN) {
                color[x][y] = temp.getPixel(x, y);
                float[] hsv = new float[3];
                Color.RGBToHSV(Color.red(color[x][y]), Color.green(color[x][y]), Color.blue(color[x][y]), hsv);
                hsv[0] = 360;
                color[x][y] = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
            }
            temp.setPixel(x, y, color[x][y]);
        }
    }

 imageView.setImageBitmap(temp);
```

Update:

```
 intArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight()];
                    bitmap.getPixels(intArray,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());

    int[] tempArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight()];
      temp.getPixels(tempArray,0,temp.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());

    //get the color of each pixel
    color = new int[bitmap.getWidth()][bitmap.getHeight()];
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
            if (intArray[x + y * bitmap.getWidth()] == Color.BLUE) {
                float[] hsv = new float[3];
                Color.RGBToHSV(Color.red(tempArray[x + y * bitmap.getWidth()]), Color.green(tempArray[x + y * bitmap.getWidth()]), Color.blue(tempArray[x + y * bitmap.getWidth()]), hsv);
                hsv[0] = 360;
                tempArray[x + y * bitmap.getWidth()] = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);

            }
        }
    }

    temp.setPixels(tempArray,0,temp.getWidth(),0,0,temp.getWidth(),temp.getHeight());

    imageView.setImageBitmap(temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to make this faster. Let's start with the easiest ones:

---

`float[] hsv = new float[3];`

Using `new` allocates memory on the heap, which is slow and not cache friendly (and needs to be freed afterwards (depending on the language this could be automatic)). You could (re)use a local float[3] instead.

---

```
    color[x][y] = temp.getPixel(x, y);
    if (bitmap.getPixel(x, y) == Color.GREEN) {
        color[x][y] = temp.getPixel(x, y);
```

No need to do a second `temp.getPixel()` (which can be slow) here. The data is already in `color[x][y]`.

---

```
    color[x][y] = temp.getPixel(x, y);
    if (bitmap.getPixel(x, y) == Color.GREEN) {
        // ...
    }
    temp.setPixel(x, y, color[x][y]);
```

No need to set the pixel if it didn't change. So you could move `temp.setPixel` inside the `if` block. And actually `color[x][y] = temp.getPixel(x, y);` could also go inside the `if` block (or just remove the outer one, because the same is already inside the `if` block)

---

```
color = new int[bitmap.getWidth()][bitmap.getHeight()];
```

First, you probably want to use `unsigned int` here, but actually you don't need this third array. You can just use a local `unsigned int color` variable instead.

---

```
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
```

Depending on the language, you might want to reverse the order of the loops to be more cache friendly (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_interchange)). The easiest way to make sure is to do a quick test with both orders.

---

`getPixel()` and `setPixel()` can be slow (again depending on the language). It is better to work on the pixel data directly just like on a two dimensional array. Most languages provide a function to get a pointer or access to the raw pixel data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
It is better to work on the pixel data directly just like on a two dimensional array. <-- I am quite interested in this one, would you mind to give me some further explanation, please?

Comment: @ng2b30 Instead of using `getPixel()` and `setPixel()` you can access de pixels array directly, which is much faster: `byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image

Comment: I have a question. How can I make a png image loaded from gallery to change it to be a get bufferedImage? Thanks.

Comment: Also, I need to paint some parts for the image and then get the position of coloured region. Would I detect the image color using the same method after the detection?

Comment: Oh I find another method by using the getPixels() and setPixels(). I can finish my task within 1-2 secs. btw thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I guess what I would do is determine the size of each pixel.  Most likely 32 bits ARGB.  So you have an array of WxH longs.  Loop through that array and if value is whatever G = 255 would be, then replace it.  I would also ignore the ALPHA channel